# Overwrite data in table

Tags: excel, vba

How can I overwrite data in a table depending on the values of one table?

In worksheet 1, I have the following table:
[image]

In worksheet 2, I have a table where users can manually input data
[image]

I want the data in worksheet 2 to overwrite the data in worksheet 1 depending on the reference number.

The table in worksheet 1 would look like this (*highlighted sections*) to show what looks different:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd sheet to generate new table.
I assume reference numbers are unique. And if reference number exists in second table, all values (City, Earnings, Credit Card Type) are filled.
Let say first table is in `Sheet1` and second is in `Sheet2`. Create `Sheet3`, add formula to `A2` and drag it down:

```
=IF(IFNA(MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0),0),TOROW(HSTACK(Sheet1!A2:B2,VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:D,2,FALSE),Sheet1!D2,VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:D,{3,4},FALSE))),TOROW(Sheet1!A2:F2))
```

Result:
[image]

Formula checks if reference number exist in Sheet2 table. If not - it copies values from 1st table. If it exists, it combines row from both 1st and 2nd tables and spills it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I'm getting a #NAME! error for the Torow and Hstack functions. Normally I'm on office 365 so shouldn't pose a problem. Do I need to enable these functions to be able to use them? Thanks again

Comment: Are your sheetnames correct? Try =TOROW(Sheet1!A2:F2) to simply see if it spills any data

Comment: Hi, yes unfortunately I still get the same error when I tried the shorter formula. Sheet names are definitely correct.

Comment: Well if only hstack and torow functions throws an error, than might indicate that excel version is other than 365

Comment: It's strange as it says that I have 365 in my account. Is there something I can do to enable formulas? If not is there another formula that I could use?

Comment: You may have, but is it installed? You can check your Excel program version File-> Account -> Right side "Product information". Also is your file you are working on .xlsx format?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250752/discussion-between-bikat-uprety-and-user11222393).